# Сортировка методом пузырка по возрастанию,прочитав через файл

Tags: c++

```
static int V,n;
std::ifstream read("26.txt");
read>>V;
read>>n;
int a[n];
for(unsigned int i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
    read>>a[i];
}

for(unsigned int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){

    for(unsigned int j = 0;j<n-i-1;j++){

        if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
            V = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
            a[j + 1] = V;
    }
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cout << a[i] <<std::endl;;
}
}
return 0;
```

}
Я написал код,который берет из файла числа и сортирует их методом пузырка в порядке возрастания,но почему то он не работает верно,помогите пожайлуста.Заранее благодарю.

Comment: фигурную скобку `}` запустил далеко. Сначала нужен **двойной** цикл сортировки, потом **одиночный** вывода.

Comment: где должна быть?

Comment: я убрал да,но все равно нету результата,там рандомные числа,и они не в возрастании

Comment: там даже **две** скобки оказывается не там.

Comment: зачем вы считываете из файла переменную `V` ?

Comment: смотрите,там V=8200,а n=970,

Comment: V-свободный обьем на архивном диске по задаче,а n-количество пользователей

Comment: @AlexGlebe не знаю как осуществить это.Что надо исправить?